Import "comtypes .client" could not be resolved
I am new to programming. I was watching a video on how to automate ETABS with Python.
When trying to run the code provided by ETABS but I got the error 'Import "comtypes .client" could not be resolved'.

I installed the 'comtypes' library and still have the same problem.

If anyone has used the ETABS api previously can help me if you have had the same error
import os
import sys
import comtypes.client

#set the following flag to True to attach to an existing instance of the program
#otherwise a new instance of the program will be started
AttachToInstance = False

#set the following flag to True to manually specify the path to ETABS.exe
#this allows for a connection to a version of ETABS other than the latest installation
#otherwise the latest installed version of ETABS will be launched
SpecifyPath = False

#if the above flag is set to True, specify the path to ETABS below
ProgramPath = "C:\Program Files\Computers and Structures\ETABS 21\ETABS.exe"

#full path to the model
#set it to the desired path of your model
APIPath = 'C:\CSi_ETABS_API_Example'
if not os.path.exists(APIPath):
    try:
        os.makedirs(APIPath)
    except OSError:
        pass
ModelPath = APIPath + os.sep + 'API_1-001.edb'

#create API helper object
helper = comtypes.client.CreateObject('ETABSv1.Helper')
helper = helper.QueryInterface(comtypes.gen.ETABSv1.cHelper)

if AttachToInstance:
    #attach to a running instance of ETABS
    try:
        #get the active ETABS object
        myETABSObject = helper.GetObject("CSI.ETABS.API.ETABSObject") 
    except (OSError, comtypes.COMError):
        print("No running instance of the program found or failed to attach.")
        sys.exit(-1)
else:
    if SpecifyPath:
        try:
            #'create an instance of the ETABS object from the specified path
            myETABSObject = helper.CreateObject(ProgramPath)
        except (OSError, comtypes.COMError):
            print("Cannot start a new instance of the program from " + ProgramPath)
            sys.exit(-1)
    else:
        try: 
            #create an instance of the ETABS object from the latest installed ETABS
            myETABSObject = helper.CreateObjectProgID("CSI.ETABS.API.ETABSObject") 
        except (OSError, comtypes.COMError):
            print("Cannot start a new instance of the program.")
            sys.exit(-1)

    #start ETABS application
    myETABSObject.ApplicationStart()

#create SapModel object
SapModel = myETABSObject.SapModel

#initialize model
SapModel.InitializeNewModel()

#create new blank model
ret = SapModel.File.NewBlank()

#define material property
MATERIAL_CONCRETE = 2
ret = SapModel.PropMaterial.SetMaterial('CONC', MATERIAL_CONCRETE)

#assign isotropic mechanical properties to material
ret = SapModel.PropMaterial.SetMPIsotropic('CONC', 3600, 0.2, 0.0000055)

#define rectangular frame section property
ret = SapModel.PropFrame.SetRectangle('R1', 'CONC', 12, 12)

#define frame section property modifiers
ModValue = [1000, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
ret = SapModel.PropFrame.SetModifiers('R1', ModValue)

#switch to k-ft units
kip_ft_F = 4
ret = SapModel.SetPresentUnits(kip_ft_F)

#add frame object by coordinates
FrameName1 = ' '
FrameName2 = ' '
FrameName3 = ' '
[FrameName1, ret] = SapModel.FrameObj.AddByCoord(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, FrameName1, 'R1', '1', 'Global')
[FrameName2, ret] = SapModel.FrameObj.AddByCoord(0, 0, 10, 8, 0, 16, FrameName2, 'R1', '2', 'Global')
[FrameName3, ret] = SapModel.FrameObj.AddByCoord(-4, 0, 10, 0, 0, 10, FrameName3, 'R1', '3', 'Global')

#assign point object restraint at base
PointName1 = ' '
PointName2 = ' '
Restraint = [True, True, True, True, False, False]
[PointName1, PointName2, ret] = SapModel.FrameObj.GetPoints(FrameName1, PointName1, PointName2)
ret = SapModel.PointObj.SetRestraint(PointName1, Restraint)

#assign point object restraint at top
Restraint = [True, True, False, False, False, False]
[PointName1, PointName2, ret] = SapModel.FrameObj.GetPoints(FrameName2, PointName1, PointName2)
ret = SapModel.PointObj.SetRestraint(PointName2, Restraint)

#refresh view, update (initialize) zoom
ret = SapModel.View.RefreshView(0, False)

#add load patterns
LTYPE_OTHER = 8
ret = SapModel.LoadPatterns.Add('1', LTYPE_OTHER, 1, True)
ret = SapModel.LoadPatterns.Add('2', LTYPE_OTHER, 0, True)
ret = SapModel.LoadPatterns.Add('3', LTYPE_OTHER, 0, True)
ret = SapModel.LoadPatterns.Add('4', LTYPE_OTHER, 0, True)
ret = SapModel.LoadPatterns.Add('5', LTYPE_OTHER, 0, True)
ret = SapModel.LoadPatterns.Add('6', LTYPE_OTHER, 0, True)
ret = SapModel.LoadPatterns.Add('7', LTYPE_OTHER, 0, True)

#assign loading for load pattern 2
[PointName1, PointName2, ret] = SapModel.FrameObj.GetPoints(FrameName3, PointName1, PointName2)
PointLoadValue = [0,0,-10,0,0,0]
ret = SapModel.PointObj.SetLoadForce(PointName1, '2', PointLoadValue)
ret = SapModel.FrameObj.SetLoadDistributed(FrameName3, '2', 1, 10, 0, 1, 1.8, 1.8)

#assign loading for load pattern 3
[PointName1, PointName2, ret] = SapModel.FrameObj.GetPoints(FrameName3, PointName1, PointName2)
PointLoadValue = [0,0,-17.2,0,-54.4,0]
ret = SapModel.PointObj.SetLoadForce(PointName2, '3', PointLoadValue)

#assign loading for load pattern 4
ret = SapModel.FrameObj.SetLoadDistributed(FrameName2, '4', 1, 11, 0, 1, 2, 2)

#assign loading for load pattern 5
ret = SapModel.FrameObj.SetLoadDistributed(FrameName1, '5', 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 'Local')
ret = SapModel.FrameObj.SetLoadDistributed(FrameName2, '5', 1, 2, 0, 1, -2, -2, 'Local')

#assign loading for load pattern 6
ret = SapModel.FrameObj.SetLoadDistributed(FrameName1, '6', 1, 2, 0, 1, 0.9984, 0.3744, 'Local')
ret = SapModel.FrameObj.SetLoadDistributed(FrameName2, '6', 1, 2, 0, 1, -0.3744, 0, 'Local')

#assign loading for load pattern 7
ret = SapModel.FrameObj.SetLoadPoint(FrameName2, '7', 1, 2, 0.5, -15, 'Local')

#switch to k-in units
kip_in_F = 3
ret = SapModel.SetPresentUnits(kip_in_F)

#save model
ret = SapModel.File.Save(ModelPath)

#run model (this will create the analysis model)
ret = SapModel.Analyze.RunAnalysis()

#initialize for results
ProgramResult = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[PointName1, PointName2, ret] = SapModel.FrameObj.GetPoints(FrameName2, PointName1, PointName2)

#get results for load cases 1 through 7
for i in range(0,7):
      NumberResults = 0
      Obj = []
      Elm = []
      ACase = []
      StepType = []
      StepNum = []
      U1 = []
      U2 = []
      U3 = []
      R1 = []
      R2 = []
      R3 = []
      ObjectElm = 0
      ret = SapModel.Results.Setup.DeselectAllCasesAndCombosForOutput()
      ret = SapModel.Results.Setup.SetCaseSelectedForOutput(str(i + 1))
      if i <= 3:
          [NumberResults, Obj, Elm, ACase, StepType, StepNum, U1, U2, U3, R1, R2, R3, ret] = SapModel.Results.JointDispl(PointName2, ObjectElm, NumberResults, Obj, Elm, ACase, StepType, StepNum, U1, U2, U3, R1, R2, R3)
          ProgramResult[i] = U3[0]
      else:
          [NumberResults, Obj, Elm, ACase, StepType, StepNum, U1, U2, U3, R1, R2, R3, ret] = SapModel.Results.JointDispl(PointName1, ObjectElm, NumberResults, Obj, Elm, ACase, StepType, StepNum, U1, U2, U3, R1, R2, R3)
          ProgramResult[i] = U1[0]

#close the program
ret = myETABSObject.ApplicationExit(False)
SapModel = None
myETABSObject = None

#fill independent results
IndResult = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
IndResult[0] = -0.02639
IndResult[1] = 0.06296
IndResult[2] = 0.06296
IndResult[3] = -0.2963
IndResult[4] = 0.3125
IndResult[5] = 0.11556
IndResult[6] = 0.00651

#fill percent difference
PercentDiff = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
for i in range(0,7):
      PercentDiff[i] = (ProgramResult[i] / IndResult[i]) - 1

#display results
for i in range(0,7):
      print()
      print(ProgramResult[i])
      print(IndResult[i])
      print(PercentDiff[i])

Error:



Can you show the code that generated this error?

Ok.. its edited

Your code is correct and python interpreter can understand it. ref

Absolute imports may use either the import <> or from <> import <> syntax

But for pylance, you should use from <> import <> syntax.
Try below code:
import os
import sys
from comtypes import client

# rest of your code


Note:
pylance is a linter, and oftentimes pylance errors don't necessarily mean your code is wrong.
